# How to see that $\Delta(X)\le nw(X)$ for any regular spce?

Tags: general-topology

How to see that $\Delta(X)\le nw(X)$ for any regular spce?

$\Delta(X)$ and $ nw(X)$ are two  [cardinal function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_function) on $X$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Note that neither the diagonal degree nor the net weight are defined in that Wikipedia article.

Comment: @Arthur: You obviously don’t need it for these, but you may find [this PS file](http://math.berkeley.edu/~apollo/topodefs.ps) useful at some point; it’s a remarkably comprehensive collection of definitions of terms used in general topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$Let $\mathscr{N}$ be a network for $X$ of cardinality $nw(X)$. Suppose that $U$ is an open nbhd of some $x\in X$. $X$ is regular, so there is an open $V$ such that $x\in V\subseteq\cl V\subseteq U$. Then there is an $N\in\mathscr{N}$ such that $x\in N\subseteq V$, so $x\in\cl N\subseteq\cl V\subseteq U$. Thus, $\{\cl N:N\in\mathscr{N}\}$ is a network for $X$, and we may therefore assume without loss of generality that each $N\in\mathscr{N}$ is closed.

Let $$\mathscr{P}=\left\{\{M,N\}\in[\mathscr{N}]^2:M\cap N=\varnothing\right\}\;,$$

where as usual $[\mathscr{N}]^2$ is the family of two-element subsets of $\mathscr{N}$. For each $P=\{M,N\}\in\mathscr{P}$ let $\mathscr{U}(P)=\{X\setminus M,X\setminus N\}$, an open cover of $X$.

Fix $x\in X$. If $y\in X\setminus\{x\}$, there is a $P=\{M,N\}\in\mathscr{P}$ such that $x\in M$ and $y\in N$. Clearly, then, $y\notin\operatorname{st}(x,\mathscr{U}(P))=X\setminus N$. Thus,

$$\bigcap_{P\in\mathscr{P}}\operatorname{st}(x,\mathscr{U}(P))=\{x\}\;.$$

And $x$ was arbitrary, so $\Delta(X)\le|\mathscr{P}|\le|\mathscr{N}|=nw(X)$.